# undefined method when trying to get the first day of the week - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a calendar, I'm trying to get the first day of the week, as well as the last day of the week. When trying to do this, I get an error in `/lib/calencar.rb`:

```
undefined method `beginning_of_month 'for {: date => Wed, 23 Jan 2019}: Hash
```

This is the code calendar.rb

```
class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
    START_DAY = :sunday

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def table
      content_tag :table, class: "calendar table table-bordered table-striped" do
        header + week_rows
      end
    end

    def header
      content_tag :tr do
        HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
      end
    end

    def week_rows
      weeks.map do |week|
        content_tag :tr do
          week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
        end
      end.join.html_safe
    end

    def day_cell(day)
      content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
    end

    def day_classes(day)
      classes = []
      classes << "today" if day == Date.today
      classes << "not-month" if day.month != date.month
      classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
    end

    def weeks
      #first = DateTime.strptime(date, "%B %d, %Y")
      first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
      last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
      (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
    end
end
```

Also, in the `index#index` controller I have the following code:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    helper CalendarHelper
  def index
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
  end
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
undefined method `beginning_of_month 'for {: date => Wed, 23 Jan 2019}: Hash
```

You are trying to use a `beginning_of_month` method on a `Hash` not on a `DateTime` object, check the assignment of your `date` variable.

Comment: Now I get another error: `no block given (yield)` in `content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)`

Comment: Remove the `&callback`from `capture`

Comment: It looks like this:` content_tag: td, view.capture (day), class: day_classes (day)`, but it still shows the same error

Comment: You need to pass a `&block` to `capture`, https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/capture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188941/discussion-between-elpapu-and-vzamanillo).